# Hide entire parent element if child is null React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am new to React, I want to hide parent div if child is having null, li data is passing with props

```
import React from 'react';

const PublicationTags = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="publication-tags">
            <h4>Темы публикации</h4>
            <ul>
                {props.data &&
                    props.data.tag_names &&
                    props.data.tag_names.map((tag_name, key) => (
                        <li key={key}>
                            <a href="/">{tag_name}</a>
                        </li>
                    ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};

export default PublicationTags;
```

If there is no data on li items I want to hide the  and  tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ParentDiv style={this.props.data===null ? {display:'none'}:{display:'flex'}>{this.props.data}</ParentDiv>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the whole structure of the app but you could do something like:

```
import React from 'react';

const PublicationTags = props => {
  if (!props.data.length) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div className="publication-tags">
      <h4>Темы публикации</h4>
      <ul>
        {props.data &&
          props.data.tag_names &&
          props.data.tag_names.map((tag_name, key) => (
            <li key={key}>
              <a href="/">{tag_name}</a>
            </li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PublicationTags;
```

or:

```
import React from 'react';

const PublicationTags = props => {
  return props.data.length ? (
    <div className="publication-tags">
      <h4>Темы публикации</h4>
      <ul>
        {props.data &&
          props.data.tag_names &&
          props.data.tag_names.map((tag_name, key) => (
            <li key={key}>
              <a href="/">{tag_name}</a>
            </li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  ) : null;
};

export default PublicationTags;
```

Comment: Above code is not hiding the entire div.publication-tags

Comment: On the return line I added props.data.length which should work.